# Liveness probe failed: timeout: failed to connect service ":8080" within 1s

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, minikube, livenessprobe

While deploying microservices on Kubernetes with minikube I faced the problem of Liveness probe failure. Based on this answer I changed the timeoutSeconds of liveness probe from 1 to 10, but the problem isn't fixed. [Readiness probe failed: timeout: failed to connect service ":8080" within 1s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060336/readiness-probe-failed-timeout-failed-to-connect-service-8080-within-1s)

The error says,

```
Liveness probe failed: timeout: failed to connect service ":8080" within 1s
Back-off restarting failed container.
```

What else could i do to solve this?

Comment: please post more information into your question, like the pod template, logs, etc. Using a similiar question to illustrate yours is not enough

Comment: Thanks to follow this link : [Readiness probe failed: timeout: failed to connect service “:8080” within 1s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060336/readiness-probe-failed-timeout-failed-to-connect-service-8080-within-1s) he can help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: i deployed the same microservices, from the online boutique by Google demo app https://github.com/newrelic-forks/microservices-demo . It is the recommendaτionservice deployment that has the problem.

Comment: livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/grpc_health_probe
                - '-addr=:8080'
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed it by increasing timeout and adding startupProbe:

> ```
>     readinessProbe:
>        initialDelaySeconds: 5
>        timeoutSeconds: 3
>        successThreshold: 1
>        failureThreshold: 3
>        periodSeconds: 5
>        exec:
>          command: ["/bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8080"]
>      livenessProbe:
>        initialDelaySeconds: 15
>        #timeoutSeconds: 3
>        periodSeconds: 5
>        successThreshold: 1
>        failureThreshold: 3
>        exec:
>          command: ["/bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8080"]
>      startupProbe:
>        exec:
>          command: [ "/bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8080" ]
>        failureThreshold: 30
>        periodSeconds: 10
> ```